# how to get property out of json response in cypress

Tags: json, cypress

i have cypress request call returning Json array
 `{ids:[one, two, three]}`
How can i parse out one of the array values from the body of response and pass it to the next test?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the given information I guess what you want is [Asserting Network Calls from Cypress Tests](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/12/23/asserting-network-calls-from-cypress-tests/).

There is a good example in the [cypress-example-recipes](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/server-communication__xhr-assertions/cypress/integration/spec.js)

I guess you could do something like

```js
describe('Test', () => {
  let ids;

  it('gets expected response', () => {
    cy.server()
    cy.route('GET', '/url').as('response')
    cy.visit("url")
   
    // log the request object
    cy.get('@response').then(console.log) 
  
    // confirm the request status
    cy.get('@response').should('have.property', 'status', 200)

    // confirm the request's response
    cy.get('@response').its('response').then((res) => {
      expect(res.body).to.deep.equal({
        "ids": ["one", "two", "three"]
      })
     
      // store the ids in a variable
      ids = JSON.parse(res.body)?.ids
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Tried most of it, the problem here: when i do ids = JSON.parse(res.body), cypress is complaining for invalid characters in json

Comment: If your response is really formatted `{ids:[one, two, three]}` - that's not valid JSON. Please refer to https://jsonlint.com/ or elaborate further what you really want to do.

Comment: i used "cy.log" to print values and that misled.... it is actually valid json and it was already parsed into the object; i used "res.body.ids[0]" to get first member of array and that worked

Comment: Glad to here that it worked! Consider accepting this answer if it helped.